# Download File in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to write a script in Yii for downloading files from the server.

The files are located in webroot of the Yii project,

but I got every time file not exist error, could anyone see where is wrong:

```
public function actionDownload($id) {
    $audio = Audio::model()->findByPk($id);
    $file =  Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . $audio->path;
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $audio->path);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($audio->path));
        $audio->downloaded = $audio->downloaded + 1;
        $audio->save();
    }else{
        echo "file not exist: ".$file;            
    }
    exit;
}
```

error I got is:

```
file not exist: /var/www/vhosts/ikhwanbiz.org/httpdocs/userfiles/reklames/media/deneme/sen%20dep%20olmisem.mp3
```

Thanks

Regards

Bili

Comment: did you try some file without spaces in the name?

Comment: you are right, the spaces causes the problem, there is nothing wrong in the code! thanks

Comment: @Xiabili: Actually it's not only spaces that will cause this problem. Most special characters will cause the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bili, this works well for me and seem to be fine on most browsers.

```
$filename = 'your_file_name.csv';
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; charset=UTF-8; filename="'.$filename.'"');
$utf8_content = mb_convert_encoding($content, "SJIS", "UTF-8");
echo $utf8_content;
Yii::app()->end();
return;
```

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: xiabili: by the way, could you upvote my answer please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the filename portion `$audio->path` is URL-encoded, while the name of the actual file on the server is not. You should fix it at the source (no idea where that path is set from), but in the meantime an easy workaround would be to write

```
$file =  Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . urldecode($audio->path);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a php question than a yii one.

for eg,

```
<?php
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=huge_document.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile("huge_document.pdf");
?>
```

source: http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm